# Change upload directory for PDF files

Tags: directory, uploads

I would like to change the upload directory for PDF files **only**, not for other files. For example, the PDF files would be uploaded to `wp-content/uploads/pdf` but other files would remain in `wp-content/uploads/yyyy/mm`.

I know it possible to filter `upload_dir` but I don't know how to do it with file types/mimes.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help you:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/use-a-separate-upload-folder-for-custom-post-attachment-upload

Answer (score 18):

Following *Justice Is Cheap* lead, I ended adapting the functions from this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/

```
<?php
/* 
 * Change upload directory for PDF files 
 * Only works in WordPress 3.3+
 */

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse47415_pre_upload');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'wpse47415_post_upload');

function wpse47415_pre_upload($file){
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse47415_custom_upload_dir');
    return $file;
}

function wpse47415_post_upload($fileinfo){
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse47415_custom_upload_dir');
    return $fileinfo;
}

function wpse47415_custom_upload_dir($path){    
    $extension = substr(strrchr($_POST['name'],'.'),1);
    if(!empty($path['error']) ||  $extension != 'pdf') { return $path; } //error or other filetype; do nothing. 
    $customdir = '/pdf';
    $path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); //remove default subdir (year/month)
    $path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);      
    $path['subdir']  = $customdir;
    $path['path']   .= $customdir; 
    $path['url']    .= $customdir;  
    return $path;
}
```

Comment: Hi ... need to upload outside "/wp-content/uploads/" folder. Please help

Answer (score 1):

you can change upload directory from wp-config.php file in wordpress.

define('UPLOADS', 'myimages');
Make sure you add this code before the line:

require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);

this is allows you to upload media in myimages folder instead of wp-content/uploads

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The initial problem was to change the upload folder for `pdf` files only.