# Upload video in custom folder

Tags: media, uploads

I am trying to find a system to upload some kind of media in a custom folder.
I want to keep all uploads in default wordpress folder and create a custom folder just for videos.

So i would have the following folder structure:

```
- wp-content
  - uploads
    - year
    - month
  - videos
    - category-one
    - category two
```

In addition i would like that the files stored in this new folder should be listed in media library.

Comment: Researching the site is always worthy: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47415/12615

Comment: Ok, you wrote that you adapted functions of this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/   Which file of this plugin you modified? in which part of the file you placed that code?

Comment: Don't remember which file... The code I posted is autonomous, see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615