# Restricted Attachments/Change Attachment Upload Location

Tags: attachments

I need a way to have certain post attachments (images/pdfs/etc) be restricted to specific logged in users.

What is the best way to do this?

At a high level it seem like I need to do the following:

1. Divert the attachment to a secured folder (eg. outside of the
   webroot).
2. Write a controller of some sort to check if the user is
   allowed to access the file and then output the bits of the file if
   they are.

I can do step one based on the filename using something like the [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50805) in [*Change upload directory for PDF files*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47415/change-upload-directory-for-pdf-files).

However, when I do that I can't figure out how to change the attachment URL that Wordpress generates so that I can do step 2. Wordpress assumes that it's still in the normal upload directory.

So, how do I change the URL when I'm changing the upload directory and is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Have you considered adding custom capabilities?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities  Test if a user has cap to allow access?

Comment: @jdm2112 Yes, but that doesn't prevent someone with the link accessing the file directly.

Comment: How would they get the link?

Comment: Copy/paste from a friend? Guessing? Etc.

Comment: How many images are you trying to restrict and to how many users?  You could use a filter to prevent specific imgs from showing to anyone not user x or y but that's highly manual.  How about a CPT to house these images and then restrict the pos type to a specific role?

Comment: I'm not really sure how that would work. The files still get uploaded to `wp-content\uploads` which is accessible directly without going through any Wordpress code.